# Edit HTML using Microsoft HTML document class in Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, dom

I am trying edit a HTML file in powershell, I want to remove the tag head and it contents and add CSS element style and it's contents to the HTML file. I am using Microsoft HTML document class to access HTML file.
I am getting error The assignment expression is not valid at this line "$($($HTML.getElementsByTagName('head')).innerHTML) = $CssContent" in powershell

> HTML file

```
<html xmlns:string="xalan://java.lang.String" xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Summary</title>
<link rel="sheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href="sheet.css">
</head>
```

> CSS content to be replaced in HTML file

```
body {
    font:normal 68% verdana,arial,helvetica;
    color:#000000;
}
table tr td, table tr th {
    font-size: 68%;
}
```

> powershell Script

```
#get contents of file
$Content = Get-Content 'test.html' -raw
$CssContent = Get-Content 'test.css' -raw

# Create HTML file Object
$HTML = New-Object -Com "HTMLFile"
$HTML.IHTMLDocument2_write($Content)

#Assign InnerHTML to CssContent
$($($HTML.getElementsByTagName('head')).innerHTML) = $CssContent
#the error i get is "The assignment expression is not valid at this line"
```

Comment: Why are you not just using the built-in PowerShell cmdlets for XML?  ---  `Get-Command -Name '*xml*'`.

Comment: Assigning CSS to `innerHTML` makes no sense. You would have to append a `style` element as child of `head` element.

Comment: i was planning to use powershell replace to add style into the HTML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment.

You can also use RegEx, for this use case, though it is frowned upon relative to using the XML cmdlets.

```
($HtmlContent = @"
<html xmlns:string="xalan://java.lang.String" xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Summary</title>
<link rel="sheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href="sheet.css">
</head>
"@ )
# Results
<#
<html xmlns:string="xalan://java.lang.String" xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Summary</title>
<link rel="sheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href="sheet.css">
</head>
#>

($CssContent = @'
body {
    font:normal 68% verdana,arial,helvetica;
    color:#000000;
}
table tr td, table tr th {
    font-size: 68%;
}
'@)
# Results
<#
body {
    font:normal 68% verdana,arial,helvetica;
    color:#000000;
}
table tr td, table tr th {
    font-size: 68%;
}
#>

# Using a multi-line RegEx tag HTML tag match
($NewHtmlContent = $HtmlContent -replace '(?ms)^\<head.*?</head>', $CssContent)
# Results
<#
<html xmlns:string="xalan://java.lang.String" xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
body {
    font:normal 68% verdana,arial,helvetica;
    color:#000000;
}
table tr td, table tr th {
    font-size: 68%;
}

#>
```